# Best approximation of nonlinear Eq using simulink blocks

Tags: matlab

I'm interested to know wheathere there are any way to get the best approximation of nonlinear Eq ([My nonlin Eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdxsv.png)) using matlab's simulink blocks?
(`dx/dt` means `x` derivative related to `t`)

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider solving these equations in MATLAB and send/receive data via `simin/simout` blocks?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html